# Append a param onto the current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'd like to have a little easter egg button in the corner of a project site. When clicked, it just drops a string onto the current url and reloads the page.

So if I'm on:
http://test.com/projects/view/134

*The button is clicked*

Page reload on:
http://test.com/projects/view/134?ts=true

Not really sure how I might go about doing so though.

Answer (score 33):

try this code,

```
var separator = (window.location.href.indexOf("?")===-1)?"?":"&";
window.location.href = window.location.href + separator + "ts=true";
```

EDITS:
to avoid duplicated parameter or very large string in your url, you need to replace the old param it already exists.

```
var url=window.location.href,
    separator = (url.indexOf("?")===-1)?"?":"&",
    newParam=separator + "ts=true";
    newUrl=url.replace(newParam,"");
    newUrl+=newParam;
    window.location.href =newUrl;
```

Comment: but what if the URL contains a hash?

Comment: @fabiangebert: `location.hash` will gives you the hash value. hope you can update the rest as you needed :)

Comment: This doesn't avoid the duplicate parameter as you assume the new param has the same value as the old one. But can work if you add a regex for the old one, such as `rparam =  separator + "ts=",
                    newParam = param + $(this).val(),
                    regex = new RegExp(param+"[^\&]*");
                    newUrl = url.replace(regex, "");`

Answer (score 27):

You can assign [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to the value it currently has, plus your new querystring:

(edited to be friendly to existing querystrings)

```
$("#yourButtonId").click({
    var loc = location.href;
    if (loc.indexOf("?") === -1)
       loc += "?";
    else
       loc += "&";
    location.href = loc + "ts=true";
});
```

Or to be more succinct:

```
$("#yourButtonId").click({
    var loc = location.href;        
    loc += loc.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&";

    location.href = loc + "ts=true";
});
```

Answer (score 16):

Using:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL
- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Example:

```
var url = new URL("http://foo.bar/?x=1&y=2");

// If your expected result is "http://foo.bar/?x=1&y=2&x=42"
url.searchParams.append('x', 42);

// If your expected result is "http://foo.bar/?x=42&y=2"
url.searchParams.set('x', 42);

// Build result
url.toString();
```

Comment: sadly not yet supported by all browsers  https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

Comment: @iftah according to the documentation `URL` can be accessed on non-supporting browsers through calling `window.URL`......Ex.(`new window.URL('url')`) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 5):

Make full use of the `location` DOM API, and count in hash:

```js
location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + location.pathname + 
    (location.search ? location.search + '&a=b' : '?a=b') +
    location.hash;
```

Comment: I believe you missed location.hostname, should be
`location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + location.pathname + `...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to account for the potential existence of a hash "#" in the URL, proceed as follows:

```
var href = location.href;
var hasQuery = href.indexOf("?") + 1;
var hasHash = href.indexOf("#") + 1;
var appendix = (hasQuery ? "&" : "?") + "ts=true";
location.href = hasHash ? href.replace("#", appendix + "#") : href + appendix;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the previous answers lacking and as such here is a method that better handles other parameters in current querystring

```
appendToQueryString = function (param, val) {
    var queryString = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    var parameterListRaw = queryString == "" ? [] : queryString.split("&");
    var parameterList = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < parameterListRaw.length; i++) {
        var parameter = parameterListRaw[i].split("=");
        parameterList[parameter[0]] = parameter[1];
    }
    parameterList[param] = val;

    var newQueryString = "?";
    for (var item in parameterList) {
        if (parameterList.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            newQueryString += item + "=" + parameterList[item] + "&";
        }
    }
    newQueryString = newQueryString.replace(/&$/, "");
    return location.origin + location.pathname + newQueryString;
}
```

You have to use `location.href = appendToQueryString(ts, true)` to actually reload the page.

Comment: So you split the whole query string, add one element and put it back together? Why would you do that instead of just appending the new parameter? makes no sense to me.

Comment: @HorstJahns to avoid params are being duplicated

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#yourButtonId").click(function() {
       var currentUrl = window.location.pathname + "?ts=true";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation of the history API :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Example of usage:

> `var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
>   history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);`

Answer (score 0):

An improvement from @Bobbzorzen answer, with ability to delete param by passing its name only:

```
function AlterQueryString(param, val) {
    var queryString = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    var parameterListRaw = queryString == "" ? [] : queryString.split("&");
    var parameterList = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < parameterListRaw.length; i++) {
        var parameter = parameterListRaw[i].split("=");
        if (typeof val != 'undefined') {
            parameterList[parameter[0]] = parameter[1];
        } else if (param != parameter[0]) {
            parameterList[parameter[0]] = parameter[1];
        }
    }
    if (typeof val != 'undefined') {
        parameterList[param] = val;
    }

    var newQueryString = Object.keys(parameterList).length > 0 ? "?" : "";
    for (var item in parameterList) {
        if (parameterList.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            newQueryString += item + "=" + parameterList[item] + "&";
        }
    }
    newQueryString = newQueryString.replace(/&$/, "");
    return location.origin + location.pathname + newQueryString;
}
```

[gist: https://gist.github.com/envil/bc1832503bef55ffdabb0cde32bb06f1](https://gist.github.com/envil/bc1832503bef55ffdabb0cde32bb06f1)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced the `history.pushState(page, caption, replace_url)` that should not reload your page. OR if you want to modify while page load you can do this.

```
var currentURL = www.getitsol.com;
window.location.replace(currentURL + "?data=" + data.result, "_self");
```