# How to put a query in url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

I want to put a query in a URL using JavaScript, how can I do that?

Comment: `var foo = 'http://example.com?foo=bar'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append a param onto the current URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737615/append-a-param-onto-the-current-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess, `document.location.search` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

`location.href += '?ts=true';`

Refer: [Append a param onto the current URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737615/append-a-param-onto-the-current-url)

Comment: is there any away to add just one query? (instead of a infinite loop of queries)?

Comment: You should make your question clearer. Could you make some illustration examples?

Comment: to do something like this:                                                                                   original: http://server/myapp.php?id=10                                                                  what i want: http://server/myapp.php?id=10&enabled=true

Comment: I think this would be simple:
`window.location.href + '&enabled=true'`