# How to add multiple 'Get' on URL?

Tags: php

Im working on a php project and first a have a value on url for example :

```
http:www.c/com/app.php?doctor_id=12
```

And then i want to add an another value on that url without losing the doctor id

```
For example : http:www.c/com/app.php?doctor_id=12?appoin_date=11pm
```

Also when i get the doctor id it redirects the appoin page :)

Comment: You can do this using javascript

Comment: Can u tell me how ?

Comment: use & to separate subsequent ones (e.g. ?id=1&age=2&length=test

Comment: Check this answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8737675/9019169

Comment: `?doctor_id=12?appoin_date=11pm` is not the correct structure for a querystring. Individual parameters must be separated by `&`. So `?doctor_id=12&appoin_date=11pm` is correct.

Comment: IT WAS A EXAMPLE :A

Comment: Well an example is not much use if it's invalid

Comment: use a & to separate different arguments not ?. Also your url is not valid unfortuantely

Answer (score 1):

Do not generate a URL-encoded query string yourself. Use the [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function for this. The function also takes over the necessary escaping of the parameters. Example:

```
$url = 'http:www.example.com/app.php';

$parameters = [
  'doctor_id' => 12,
  'appoin_date' => '11pm',
  'name' => 'max&moritz'
];

$url .= '?'.http_build_query($parameters);
//"http:www.example.com/app.php?doctor_id=12&appoin_date=11pm&name=max%26moritz"
```